# What happens when dereferencing a pointer to a struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say I'm using 2 structs in C like:

```
struct department {
    char name[10];
    int floor;
}

struct person {
    char name[10];
    struct department *dep;
};
```

What happens under the hood, when accessing a variable `person_1` of type `person` like this:
`(person_1.dep)->floor`.
First, the `dep` pointer is dereferenced, but after, are the first 10 of the name of the department simply skipped over to get the 4 bytes of the floor, or is there more to it?

Thanks!

Comment: "are the first 10 of the name of the department simply skipped over". That's pretty much it in general. Though there are extra alignment considerations which can result in padding between the fields. In this case, `floor` is likely to be 12 bytes and not 10 bytes from the start.

Comment: Yes, though technically speaking, the number of bytes in `floor` depends on your platform.

Comment: Assuming there was no additional padding, which is unlikely unless you added attribute packed before. Then, yes, it will skip the first 10 bytes to get `floor`.

Comment: Already `person_1.dep` does the same internally. It takes the address of `person_1` on the stack and adds 10 (or 12 or 16) to that address before reading `dep` pointer. Then the same is done when dereferencing it.